# Getting error "variable AREF has no value " in CLISP while trying to print array elements one by one

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to print the value of an array in CLISP, I wrote below function:

```
(setq x (make-array '5 :initial-contents '(a b c d e)))
(loop for i from 0 to 4 do (write aref x i))
```

But I am getting error

```
*** - PROGN: variable AREF has no value 
      The following restarts are available:
 USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of AREF.
 STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for AREF.
```

I am totally new to CLISP and not getting why I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AREF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_aref.htm) is a *function*, not a *variable*.
You are missing a set of parentheses around it: `(aref x i)`:

```
(loop for i from 0 to 4 do (write (aref x i)))
```

or just

```
(loop for e across x do (write e))
```

PS. Note that [`write`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) is a
relatively low level function.
You probably want to use a variant of `print` or `princ`.